# Javascript, how to add an object to an array, if some properties of this object dont already exist in the array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have the following array (name is always random)

```
array =
[
{
active: true,
field1: "100",
field2: "",
field3: "1",
name: 0.0020123,
ventasAnuales: "ventasAnuales",
slActive: true
},
{
active: true,
field1: "100",
field2: "",
field3: "1",
name: 0.0020123,
ventasAnuales: "ventasAnuales",
slActive: true
},
{
active: true,
field1: "100",
field2: "",
field3: "1",
name: 0.0020123,
ventasAnuales: "ventasAnuales",
slActive: true
},
{
active: true,
field1: "100",
field2: "",
field3: "1",
name: 0.0020123,
empleados: "empleados",
slActive: true
}
]
```

Now I want to add extrao objects to the array, and I do it with a concat

```
array.concat(a).filter(i => i.active)
```

Problem is that there are certains conditions I should look for before doing the concat. Like for example

1. If an object with equal field1 and has the same last but one property `ventasAnuales | empleados` already exists in the array, but field3 is different.  It should replace it

For example, given that I want to add the following object

```
{
active: true,
field1: "100",
field2: "",
field3: "2",
name: 0.0020423,
ventasAnuales: "ventasAnuales",
slActive: true
},
```

It would replace the first element of the array

2. If i add an object with the same field3 value, the  same last but one property  `ventasAnuales | empleados` and the field1 is different, it should be replaced by the new object.

For example, given that i want to add the following object.

```
{
    active: true,
    field1: "50",
    field2: "",
    field3: "1",
    name: 0.1020123,
    ventasAnuales: "ventasAnuales",
    slActive: true
    }
```

It should end up replacing the first element of the array.

How should i write my concat to make this work?

Comment: can you highlight, why you get the item at index zero?

Answer (score 1):

Just filter the array to find any items that should prevent from insertion. In case you do not find any, add the new item.

you can use `[].filter()` like so:

```
const items = […, …, …]
const containing = items.filter(item => item.active == true);
if (containing.length == 0) items.push( … )
```

but `[].every()` or `[].some()` may do as well.

Example with [`every()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every)

```
if ( !items.every( i => !i.active )) 
  items.push({ active: false })
```

In case you need to replace an existing element you can use `findIndex()` like so:

```
const items = […, …, …];
const idx = items.findIndex(itm => itm.active);


// create a new item
if (idx < 0) {
  items.push(…)
}
else {
  // update
  items[idx] = …
}
```